# Is it a reasonable practice to serialize Haskell data structures to disk just using Show/Read

Tags: haskell, serialization

I've played around with the [Text.Show.Pretty](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pretty-show/1.1/doc/html/Text-Show-Pretty.html) module, and it makes it possible to serialize out Haskell data structures like records into a nice human-readable format & still be able to deserialize them easily using `read`. The output format is even more readable than YAML and JSON.

Example serialized output for a Haskell record using `Text.Show.Pretty`:

```
Book
  { author = "Plato"
  , title = "Republic"
  , numbers = [ 123
              , 1234
              ]
  }
```

Coming from the Ruby world, I know that YAML and JSON are most Rubyists' preferred format for serializing data structures. Are Haskell Show and Read instances used often to achieve the same end in Haskell?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For big structures, I wouldn't recommend it. `read` is slower than molasses. Anecdote time: I have a program named `yeganesh`. Conceptually, it's pretty simple: read in a `[(String,Double)]` with about 2000 elements and dump out the keys sorted by their elements. I used to store this using `Show`/`Read`, but found that switching to a custom printer and parser sped up the program by a factor of 8. (Note: it's not that the parsing sped up by a factor of eight. The *whole program* sped up by a factor of eight. That means the parsing sped up by a bigger factor than that.) That made the difference between uncomfortably long pauses and instant gratification.

Comment: Was your parser based on Text.Parsec or Data.Attoparsec or something else?

Comment: @dan You can see on the [Hackage page](http://new-hackage.haskell.org/package/yeganesh) that none of `text`, `bytestring`, `binary`, `attoparsec`, etc. are part of the dependencies, so you don't even have to do something sophisticated or switch data types to get a big win! I just copied the source of `read` for my data type and cut out the bits I knew I wouldn't use.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with Daniel Wagner but if you want file that a user can manipulate with simple text editors you could use the read/show for a small set of data, aka config files.

I don't think that is a common way amongst haskellers though, I usually use parsec instead of read 'config data' and a custom class /instance instead of Show.

If you got alot of data one usually use Data.Binary or Data.Serialize.